# Computing the integral $\int_0^1dx\int_0^{1-x}dy\int_y^1\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}~dz.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help with the following triple integral:

$$\int_0^1dx\int_0^{1-x}dy\int_y^1\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}~dz.$$

Comment: I added the integral into the question for you. Nonetheless, please show what you have tried. Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Hint: change the order of integration by checking$$0\le x\le1,\,0\le y\le1-x,\,y\le z\le1$$is equivalent to$$0\le z\le1,\,0\le y\le z,\,0\le x\le1-y.$$

Comment: The comment of J.G. yields the most efficient way to calculate the integral. Another (more complicated way) is to use partial fractions for $((2-z)z)^{-1}$ en working with Sine integrals.

Comment: J.G I'm struggling.. Been so long since i last worked with sine in integrals.. I dont see how im supposed to go forward at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hint from above:
$$\int^{1}_{0}dx\int_0^{1-x}dy\int_y^1\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}dz=\int_0^1dz\int_0^{z}dy\int_0^{1-y}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}~dx.$$

From here lets do step by step:

$$\int_0^{1-y}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}~dx=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}(1-y),$$
then
$$\int^{z}_{0}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}(1-y)dy=\bigg[\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}\bigg(y-\frac{y^2}{2}\bigg)\bigg]^{z}_{0}=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}\bigg(z-\frac{z^2}{2}\bigg)$$
moreover
$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{(2-z)z}\bigg(z-\frac{z^2}{2}\bigg)=\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{2},$$
therefore the last integral:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{2}dz=\bigg[-\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{2\pi}\bigg]^{1}_{0}=\frac{1}{\pi}.$$